# How to find every specific symbol in a column and add a text in a cell next to it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So basically, I have a column of numbers. Some of them are real numbers and some are integers. I need to find all the ","s and type a number type in the cell next to it.

Sorry for bad english, hope you understood.

Comment: Can you give us an example please?

Answer (score 0):

If the cell contains a number value, I'd compare the number to the integer portion of the number like this:

```
=IF(C81=INT(C81), "integer", "real")
```

(Assuming A1 is the cell you want to evaluate.)

The function, INT, returns the integer portion of a number.

If the cell really does contain text, you can differentiate between integers and reals by looking for the comma like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",A1)),"integer", "real")
```